# Low-voltage Wires Alongside a Grounding Electrode Conductor?

Tags: grounding, ethernet, coaxial-cable

I have a bare copper Grounding Electrode Conductor running from my main panel to my main water supply in a well room (about 60 ft away). It passes through quite a few holes in my joists on its way, and (to make life easier) I'd like to use the same holes to also run Ethernet Cat 6 and Coax R6 cables to that end of the basement, too. There is a lot of talk about not running powered NM cable alongside low-voltage, but is it ok to run low-voltage wires alongside a Grounding Electrode Conductor? Any advice would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think code is concerned about low and high power in the same box.  Having the two running together is more about the shielding on the low voltage causing interference.  Decent cables should be shielded enough.  With a ground wire the problem will come with a very close lighting shrike.

Comment: Code is concerned with faults putting line voltage on the low voltage system. With a proper grounding system, the nearby lighting strike raises all the ground conductors in the house together, so there's no large difference between the voltages on them. The coax ground is (or should be) grounded to the Intersystem Bonding Terminal anyway.

Comment: "There is a lot of talk about not running powered NM cable alongside low-voltage" There is, but it is almost entirely uninformed nonsense. 60Hz AC line power is entirely too low in frequency to interfere with much of anything except unencoded audio.